# best way to implement user with trial subscription

Tags: postgresql, database-design

We have an old database implementation, in PostgreSQL, where users are dependent to an institution subscription, this is based on the `renewal_date` field of the institution table. Once this has expired users belong to an institution will no longer able to access our Saas webapp. See the image below:[image]

Now, we wanted to implement a registration functionality where users are able to register whether their institution has a subscription to our tool. For this, they will be given a 30-day free trial to our tool. So now what I did is to separate the fields that I think can be placed to their own table. See the image below:
[image]

After doing some clean up, I realise it would be redundant to implement an `expiry_date` field in the Account table to store the dates of each user and use this to know when their subscription will end knowing there is an existing `renewal_date` that we are using to check that. So this is a challenge to me because not every user that will signup has their institution already subscribe to our Saas webapp. Any great suggestion over this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: may i ask what program you used to visualize the tables?

Comment: @Tommy I'm using this webapp, https://dbdesigner.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first place, `renewal_date` is more an attribute of Account than Institution; so it's in the wrong table. But even further, I would recommend a `Subscription` entity that would define a many-to-many relationship between Account and Tools.

(Oh. You don't have Tools. Well, maybe you should. You seem to have only one tool. Can you guarantee that will forever be the case?)

Then `renewal_date` would properly be an attribute of the relationship between Account and the tool they have access to.